# Rows which appeared only once in query results

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to have rows which appeared in 25th of February and did not appear in 6th of March. I've tried to do such query:

```
SELECT favfd.day, dv.title, array_to_string(array_agg(distinct "host_name"), ',') AS affected_hosts , htmltoText(dsol.fix),
count(dv.title) FROM fact_asset_vulnerability_finding_date favfd
INNER JOIN dim_vulnerability dv USING(vulnerability_id)
INNER JOIN dim_asset USING(asset_id)
INNER JOIN dim_vulnerability_solution USING(vulnerability_id)
INNER JOIN dim_solution dsol USING(solution_id)
INNER JOIN dim_solution_highest_supercedence dshs USING (solution_id)
WHERE (favfd.day='2018-02-25' OR favfd.day='2018-03-06') AND 
dsol.solution_type='PATCH' AND dshs.solution_id=dshs.superceding_solution_id
GROUP BY favfd.day, dv.title, host_name, dsol.fix
ORDER BY favfd.day, dv.title
```

which gave me following results:
[results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ABF87.png)

I've read that I need to add something like "HAVING COUNT(*)=1" but like you can see in query results my count columns looks quite weird. Here is my results with that line added:
[results with having](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WSVz0.png)

Can you advice me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Simplify your query.  It is pretty complicated.  And you should try to put the sample data in the question as text tables.

Comment: I am unable to do so because I need fields from these tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to use a `HAVING` clause to assert your date criteria:

```
SELECT
    dv.title,
    array_to_string(array_agg(distinct "host_name"), ',') AS affected_hosts,
    htmltoText(dsol.fix),
    count(dv.title)
FROM fact_asset_vulnerability_finding_date favfd
INNER JOIN dim_vulnerability dv USING(vulnerability_id)
INNER JOIN dim_asset USING(asset_id)
INNER JOIN dim_vulnerability_solution USING(vulnerability_id)
INNER JOIN dim_solution dsol USING(solution_id)
INNER JOIN dim_solution_highest_supercedence dshs USING (solution_id)
WHERE
    dsol.solution_type = 'PATCH' AND
    dshs.solution_id = dshs.superceding_solution_id
GROUP BY dv.title, dsol.fix
HAVING
    SUM(CASE WHEN favfd.day = '2018-02-25' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 AND
    SUM(CASE WHEN favfd.day = '2018-03-06' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
ORDER BY favfd.day, dv.title
```

The only major changes I made were to remove `host_name` from the `GROUP BY` clause, because you use this column in aggregate, in the select clause.  And I added the `HAVING` clause to check your logic.

The change you should make is to replace your implicit join syntax with explicit joins.  Putting join criteria into the `WHERE` clause is considered bad practice nowadays.

Comment: Your query lists every row from 25th of February, even while they appear in 6th of march

Comment: @Vaurine Try removing `favfd.day` from the `GROUP BY` clause.